# MongoDB - Show Dbs

Tags: mongodb

> I understood mongodb `show dbs`list only the dbs if they are not
>   empty. Why this rationale and why its implemented that way to confuse
>   a typical db users who want to shift from other db world to this mongo
>   world. Why don't they simply show all the dbs.

Rephrasing: 
Once I installed mongodb instance, I logged into mongo shell and issue the command `show dbs` but its not listing the default db i.e. `test`. Why?

Comment: what is you question?

Comment: If you dont understand my question, I will put it this way. In mysql and any other DB engines, if you use show databases. It simply list the dbs, but the same thing didnt happen in mongodb. Why? This is my question. I am not asking the internals, thats upto each vendors to do their own way of implementation. My simple ask is - certain commands are common in majority of the dbs, why change the norms.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right forum for that question. As you said, that's how the MongoDB folks chose to implement, and I'd recommend asking their support team.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB lazily evaluates databases. If every time a user said `db =client["someDBName"]` a full database instance sprang to life then there would be a lot of empty databases obscuring the ones with data in them. Instead the client and server delay creation of the database until a collection is created. In Python you can force database and collection creation by using the `create_collection` command as follows:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> c=pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> c["dummydb"].create_collection("dummycol")
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'dummydb'), 'dummycol')
>>> c["dummydb"].list_collection_names()
['dummycol']
>>> c.list_database_names()
['admin', 'bonkers', 'census', 'config', 'dummydb', 'dw', 'local', 'logdb', 'test']
>>> import pymongo
>>> c.list_database_names()
['admin', 'census', 'config', 'dw', 'local', 'logdb', 'test']
>>> c=pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> c["dummydb"].create_collection("dummycol")
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'dummydb'), 'dummycol')
>>> c.list_database_names()
['admin', 'census', 'config', 'dummydb', 'dw', 'local', 'logdb', 'test']
>>>
```